# Can I use a column calculated in a SQL Server view later on in that same view?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, view

Can I use a column calculated in a SQL Server view later on in that same view?

Let's say I have the following view:

```
Select 
    t1.StartMile, t2.EndMile,  t2.EndMile- t1.StartMile as TotMile
from 
   TableStarts as t1 
inner join 
   TableEnds as t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Is there a way to edit the view to do the following

```
Select  
    t1.StartMile, t2.EndMile, t2.EndMile - t1.StartMile as TotMile, 
    TotMile + 30  as EvenMoreMiles
```

I tried this and got error:

> Invalid column name 'TotMile'

Please don't tell me to use `t2.EndMile - t1.StartMile + 30 as EvenMoreMiles`. `TotMiles` is a long case statement in my actual code.

I rather not have to create an intermediate view.

I am using SQL Server 2005.

ADDED LATER

Thanks for all the answers. I will upvote all.

The answers raise the following new question:

Given that there are thousands of rows, and `TotMiles` looks like the following, which of the answers given would be the most efficient? Or would it be most efficient to create an intermediary view?

```
CASE WHEN t .TaskType = 1  and  t .StartTime < '1/1/2012'  
               THEN (tv.EndMile - tv.StartMile )  
     WHEN NOT (t .Location1_PKey = c.pkey OR t .Location2_PKey = c.pkey)
              then (tv.EndMile - tv.StartMile )
     WHEN (tv.EndMile - tv.StartMile ) < 31  Then 0 
     ELSE  (tv.EndMile - tv.StartMile - 30 )
END AS MilesAdjusted2012,
```

Comment: When it comes to efficiency questions, the answer is usually "it depends" - we don't know what your data is like, what indexes you have, etc. We also don't know if even the hypothetically worst solution is already efficient enough for your purposes, or our best performing answer is still not enough for your circumstances/

Comment: Thanks Damien. I was being lazy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use `CROSS APPLY` which can be more concise, particularly if you are building up chains of aliases that reference preceding ones.

```
SELECT t1.StartMile,
       t2.EndMile,
       TotMile,
       EvenMoreMiles,
       AndYetMoreMiles
FROM   TableStarts AS t1
       INNER JOIN TableEnds AS t2
         ON t1.Id = t2.Id
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT t2.EndMile - t1.StartMile) A(TotMile)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TotMile + 30) A2(EvenMoreMiles)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT EvenMoreMiles + 100) A3(AndYetMoreMiles)
```

Comment: Please see section I added with a question of efficiency

Comment: @LillLansey - Nested CTEs or Nested Cross Apply's will both likely evaluate the expression once if that's what you are asking? Not much guaranteed in this area though you would need to check the execution plan to see.

Comment: @MartinSmith - does the order of the `CROSS APPLY` clauses matter?  Could you refer to a field made in your second clause from the first clause?

Comment: @JNK - Yes it does and for that reason no you couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly, but you can build up sub-selects:

```
select StartMile,EndMile,TotMile,TotMile+30 as EvenMoreMiles from (
  Select t1.StartMile, t2.EndMile,  t2.EndMile- t1.StartMile as TotMile
  from 
  TableStarts as t1 
  inner join 
  TableEnds as t2 
  on t1.Id = t2.Id  
) t
```

Or use Common Table Expressions:

```
;with FirstCalcs as (
  Select t1.StartMile, t2.EndMile,  t2.EndMile- t1.StartMile as TotMile
  from 
  TableStarts as t1 
  inner join 
  TableEnds as t2 
  on t1.Id = t2.Id  
)
select StartMile,EndMile,TotMile,TotMile+30 as EvenMoreMiles from FirstCalcs
```

I'd generally prefer to use CTEs if there's going to be a number of levels that build up the final calculations, because otherwise most formatting schemes struggle to make select, sub-select, sub-sub-select, etc, easy to read. CTEs can include references to previously defined CTEs:

```
;with CTE1 as (
    SELECT ...
), CTE2 as (
    SELECT ... FROM CTE1
), CTE3 as (
    SELECT ... FROM CTE2
), CTE4 as (
    SELECT ... FROM CTE2 ... CTE3
)
SELECT ... FROM CTE4 ... CTE1
```

Comment: Please see section I added with a question of efficiency

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Derived Table.

```
SELECT 
  DerivedTable.*,
  TotMile + 30 as EvenMoreMiles
From (Select 
        t1.StartMile, 
        t2.EndMile, 
        t2.EndMile- t1.StartMile as TotMile
        FROM Table t1 
        Inner Join table2 t2 on t1.PK = t2.FK) DerivedTable
```

Comment: Please see section I added with a question of efficiency

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a Common Table Expression (CTE).  Lots on that here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml

Basically,

```
CREATE VIEW ... AS

WITH Mileage (StartMile, EndMile, TotMile) AS (Select t1.StartMile, t2.EndMile,  t2.EndMile- t1.StartMile as TotMile
from 
TableStarts as t1 
inner join 
TableEnds as t2 
on t1.Id = t2.Id) 

SELECT TotMile FROM Mileage
```

Comment: Please see section I added with a question of efficiency